# Stop Automatic Entry Next / Previous Month Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using Trent Richardson's great [Datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). However, I'm running into a specific issue in which the plugin does not act like the traditional [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

When you start with a blank date, then press next or previous to change the month, in Datetimepicker it automatically inserts a date and time, where jQuery UI does not. The fact that it adds that is causing issues in my application, and I would just like it not to do that in the first place.

Here's my initialization:

```
 function datepickerAdd() {
        $('input[name=valueTextField]').addClass('datepicker');

                $( ".datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy ',
                        timeText: '<spring:message code='customMetaData.datetimepicker.time'/>',
                        controlType: 'select',
                        timeFormat: "h:mm TT",
                        ampm: true
                });
                $('input[name=valueTextField]').attr('onPaste', 'return false')
    }
```

Does anyone have anywhere to start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such option for Date, like `alwaysSetTime` for Time in this Datetimepicker. So you have to implement it by yourself. Just add these lines in your `datetimepicker` call:

```
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, dpInst, tpInst) {
        if(!tpInst.timeDefined && !dpInst.dateDefined) {
            this.value = '';
            dpInst.dateDefined = null;
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(date, dpInst) {
        dpInst.dateDefined = true;
    }
```

Check working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3DzTu/1/)

Comment: This is great! However, after you change you month, it doesn't allow you to still pick a date. I just want it to not automatically add, but then to allow the user to select a date if they wish. Is there anyway to do that? (This is amazing by the way!)

Comment: Gave you a plus one for the great start so far! (Also, for terms of better feedback, the event launches everytime a date is picked, not just when the month/year changes)

Comment: In addition, this solution doesn't allow for any dates to be picked at all.

Comment: Would there be a way to alter this to remove the entire API functionality that changes the input date? I feel like it would just be more user friendly! (Thank you again for your help!)

Comment: I don't get it... What do you want to do? Unfortunately all behavior is controlled by private method `_updateDateTime` which is called from different places inside plugin, so to make something more user friendly you'll need to patch plugin and this isn't a good idea if you want to be able to update it when new versions released.